# Oogli not found (OpenGL)

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I do the following:

> python -c 'import oogli'

I get back the following error:

[image: Terminal Output]

Does anyone know how to fix this?  Genuinely confused.

Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
[image: Errors]

Got back more errors.

Comment: Have you installed it using `pip` ?

Comment: @codrelphi Yeah, I did it by: "pip install oogli". No errors received while doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says to `Update GLFW_LIBRARY environment variable with path to library binary.`, so I suggest you do that.

In order to update an environment variable on MacOS, in the terminal type `nano ~/.bash_profile` and add a new line at the end with the contents `export GLFW_LIBRARY=/path/to/the/binary`.

**Edit:**

Now that you say you used `pip` to install, perhaps you should also run: `pip install glfw-cffi`, have you tried that? As it says on PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/oogli/

You also need NumPy `pip install numpy` and I assume on Mac you have Homebrew, so you must also use Homebrew to install the library to your OS: `brew install glfw3`.

The above instructions of editing environment variables are for when you have already installed the GLFW_LIBRARY, however I suspect you may not have even installed the library. During installation, the environment variables may automatically be updated.

Comment: ...and then either source the file into your existing shell or open a new terminal. Just editing the file won't affect your current session.

Comment: @RealPawPaw I've been following your instructions and as I do "brew install glfw3" I get back the following error:  ==> `brew cleanup` has not been run in 30 days, running now...
Error: Permission denied @ apply2files - /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins .

Any chance you know how to override this? 

Let me test this and report back to you.

Comment: Permission denied? Try using sudo to have root privileges: sudo brew install glfw3

Comment: @RealPawPaw I get back the following: "Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system."

Also, got more errors back now. See my updated picture ^^.

Comment: Try running in the terminal "mkdir -p /Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/cli-plugins" and then running "brew install glfw3".